# An int increments twice even though access to it is in synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

I Increment an int `OBECNA_LICZBA` in a method synchronized. So only one thread could increment it and therefeore it should be incremented by one. But it sometimes incremented by 3. Why `OBECNA_LICZBA` is incremented more then by 1?

Output in file:

```
AB000024
AB000026
AB000028
AB000030
AB000032
AB000034
AB000036
AB000038
AB000040
AB000042
AB000044
AB000046
AB000048
AB000050
AB000052
AB000054
AB000056
AB000058
```

---

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class B implements Runnable {
    private static ZasobZamkniety ZASOB;
    private static LinkedList<Pracownik> LISTA;
    private static String OBECNE_INICJALY;
    private static volatile boolean NIE_ZLAMANY = true;
    private static volatile int OBECNA_LICZBA = 0;
    private final static int MIN = 0, MAX = 999999;
    private static BufferedWriter bw = null;

    public static void fabrykaWatkow(int ileWatkow, ZasobZamkniety zasob, LinkedList<Pracownik> listaPracownikow) {
        ZASOB = zasob;
        LISTA = listaPracownikow;
        OBECNE_INICJALY = listaPracownikow.get(0).getInijcaly();
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("plik.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ileWatkow; i++)
            new Thread(new B()).start();
    }

    private B() {
    }

    public static synchronized int getObecnaLiczba(){
        return OBECNA_LICZBA;
    }
    public static synchronized String pobierzObecneHaslo() {    
        String kombinacja = getObecnaLiczba() + "";
        while (kombinacja.length() < 6)
            kombinacja = '0' + kombinacja;
        String haslo = OBECNE_INICJALY + kombinacja;
        przewin();
        return haslo;
    }

    public static synchronized void przewin(){
        OBECNA_LICZBA++;
        if (OBECNA_LICZBA > MAX && LISTA.size() > 1) {
            OBECNA_LICZBA = MIN;
            LISTA.remove();
            OBECNE_INICJALY = LISTA.element().getInijcaly();        
        }
    }

    public synchronized static void setNieZlamany(boolean wrt){
        NIE_ZLAMANY = wrt;
    }
    public static boolean getNieZlamany(){
        return NIE_ZLAMANY;
    }

    public synchronized String odpytajZasob(String hasloDoSprawdzenia){
        return ZASOB.getTresc(hasloDoSprawdzenia);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (getNieZlamany()) {
            String hasloDoSprawdzenia = pobierzObecneHaslo();       
            try {
                bw.write(hasloDoSprawdzenia);
                bw.newLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String odpowiedz = odpytajZasob(hasloDoSprawdzenia);
            if (!odpowiedz.equals(ZasobZamkniety.ZLE_HASLO)) {
                setNieZlamany(false);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, odpowiedz, "ZLAMANO HASLO", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, odpowiedz, "Czas lamania" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - Test.START), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                pobierzObecneHaslo();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's common practice to use `ALL_CAPS_NAMES` to refer to `static final` members. Using them on mutable state will confuse the reader

Comment: It is pretty hard to understand what your code is supposed to do when you use that many non-english terms in your code. Also, please try to comply with Java Code Conventions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) - That makes your code much easier to read. Last but not least: Where is your main-method? how many threads do you create? Do they have any objects in common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two calls to `pobierzObecneHaslo()` inside the `while` loop, and only one of them writes output by calling

```
bw.write(hasloDoSprawdzenia);
```

Thus, it seems that even if you assume only one thread, your value will increment by `2` between prints, which seems to be the current behavior.

Also, the way your code is currently structured, you prevent multiple threads from incrementing the variable at the same time, but you do not prevent multiple threads from running between the time when you read the value and the time you call

```
bw.write(hasloDoSprawdzenia);
```

So you could also have the problem of out-of-order printing if you have multiple threads.